# EDITED - How not to repeat loading data every time you run an imported Python script?

Tags: python, file-upload

I have 2 scripts in Python.

1. Import data script; (load_data.py - this script loads data from disk and creates a variable data, which I will use later on in many other instances)

1.(example): **load_data.py**

```
def load_data(filepath):
dictoffiles = {}
    for namefile in filepath:
        content_file = np.loadtxt(namefile)
        dictoffiles[namefile] = content_file
return dictoffiles

dictoffiles = load_data(filepath)
```

So, in this load_data.py I have *dictoffiles as the variable that contains all the data that I need*.

2. And use_data script;    (use_data.py- in this script I just want the variable created on load_data)

2.(example) **use_data.py**.

```
import load_data as im ###It runs ALL the load_data before actually get the variable I want
variable_to_use = im.dictoffiles
```

But when I import the variable that contains the data from load_data.py, it runs the whole load_data.py first and then after all it gets the variable I want, every time. This takes a lot of time.

Is there a way to cache this variable or save it somewhere in the ram of the computer then I can use it later.?

I just want to run **load_data.py once**, to save the static data into a variable, and use this variable for other scripts.
I am using Jupyter Notebook, which is fine, it does the job, but I wanted to fix it using Python code for later applications.

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. What you're describing just sounds wrong. Try to come up with an example using as few lines of code as you can, but in a way that we can reproduce on our own systems. Importing should only happen once no matter how many times you say `import` (although it's possible to force Python to reload and hence reevaluated a module).

Comment: You would need to have `load_data.py` running all the time as a server. Then client scripts could request the data via some form of [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).